# Откуда взялась тенденция писать в интернете Ь вместо Ъ?

Tags: интернет, буква

В последнее время всё чаще замечаю, что в словах "объект", "подъезд", "съезд" и других подобных словах всё чаще пишут Ь вместо Ъ в интернете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в экранной клавиатуре для набора текстов в телефонах. Там Ь и Ъ на одной кнопке. Чтобы набрать Ь - короткое нажатие, чтобы набрать Ъ - длинное. Причем некоторые клавиатуры даже не показывают Ъ, пока не нажмешь на Ь. Народу то ли лень, то ли торопятся. Тыкают пальцем в кнопку Ь коротким нажатием.

Comment: А вот про болгарский язык я вообще молчу, тем более, что буква Ъ выполняет функцию гласной буквы в словах: пъдпъдък, България, събрание.

Comment: @ТагирМанджиев болгарская кириллица несколько иная и, соответственно, клавиатура

Answer (score 1):

Думаю это в большей степени связано с тем, что на большинстве клавиатур смартфонов , для того чтобы ввести **Ъ** требуется длительное зажатие **Ь**. Кто-то об этом не знает, кто-то ленится, кто-то ошибается, но в итоге вместо твёрдого знака ставится мягкий.

Возможно со временем эта тенденция приведёт к полному упразднению твёрдого знака, как это фактически случилось в 20-е - 30-е гг. ХХ в., возможно и нет, будущее покажет.

Comment: Я считаю преждевременным любые разговоры об упразднении твёрдого знака - время покажет, тем более в эпоху интернета. Считаю, что нужно сделать обязательным наличие отдельной клавиши для буквы Ъ на экранных клавиатурах Android, iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я принципиально пишу «ь» вместо «ъ», так как не понимаю смысла писать иначе (за исключением «мемных» слов по типу «ъеъ»). Мне кажется просто невозможно спутать или прочитать неправильно слово, написанное таким образом.

Тем не менее, насчёт букв «ё» и «й» я придерживаюсь обратного мнения, так как их замена в тексте на «е» и «и» соответственно в некоторых случаях может существенно изменить как смысл, так и звучание слова (чего не происходит с «твёрдомягкими»).

В некоторых случаях даже логичнее заменить твёрдый знак на тире, например в словах «пан-европейский» или «транс-ямальский». Моё мнение - что написание «ь» или «-» вместо твёрдого знака (в зависимости от случая) стоит сделать допустимым (а может быть даже единственным верным) правилом.